# combining list elements containing similar substrings

Tags: python, list

I need to combine all elements in a list that contain same sub strings. T.ex.:

```
lst = ["A,B,C", "A,H,J", "T,Q,M", "B,R,X"]`
```

starting with first element "A,B,C" I need to look up either "A" or "B" or "C" in the rest of the elements in lst list. So by the end of the day elements `"A,B,C", "A,H,J"` and "B,R,X" should be put together as one string since they share either "A" or "B". The final lst list should look like this:

```
["A,B,C,A,H,J,B,Q,X", "T,Q,M"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*set.intersection*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) to check if the strings have any intersections within a recursion function :

```
lst = ["A,B,C", "A,H,J", "T,Q,M", "B,R,X"]

def comb(l):
   for ind,i in enumerate(l) : 
      for ix,j in enumerate(l[ind+1:]) : 
         if set(i.split(',')).intersection(j.split(',')) and len(l)>1:
               return comb([l.pop(ind)+','+l.pop(ix)]+l)

   return l

print comb(lst)
['A,B,C,A,H,J,B,R,X', 'T,Q,M']
```

Comment: Great! It seems to work. I will try to integrate it into my code

Comment: @user3468837 glad of that! so you can tell this to community with vote and accepting the answer!